# No module named pyvirtualdisplay

Tags: python, apache

I have this import in python code

```
import time
import sys
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
```

when I run it from centos consol it runs correctly without any error.

Then I created a php file to run the python script with exec php function, and when I run it from centos consol, it runs correctly too, but when I run it from the browser it gives me this error

> from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
>   ImportError: No module named pyvirtualdisplay

I tried to give apache the right of executing the python file, but still the same problem.

Any idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 11):

To be accessible from web server your modules must be installed either:

- globally with `sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay`;
- or locally with `pip --user install pyvirtualdisplay` under `apache` user;
- or in a virtual environment with `pip install pyvirtualdisplay`; the script then must be executed with python from that virtual environment; use `#!/path/to/venv/bin/python` as shebang for your scripts.

Comment: I was dumb :) I was installing python on a different server than my Apache server