# Having trouble executing Python script from PHP because of an ImportError

Tags: php, python, apache

I'm trying to execute a `Python` script from `PHP` using `exec()` like this:

`echo exec("/usr/bin/python3 timedttp.py 2>&1");`

I get `ImportError: No module named 'mpld3'`. I'm running this with `Apache` on a Raspberry Pi. The Python program is located in the same directory as my php file, and whenever I run the script in the terminal there are no problems at all. Also tried using `shell_exec()` and the error I get is the following one:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "timedttp.py", line 6, in import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3 ImportError: No module named 'mpld3'`

I'm calling the module like this inside my `Python` script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
```

I can run this program wihtout any issues from the terminal, so I think this is Apache or PHP related.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: Seems to be a python problem. Did you installed `mpld3` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Forgot to add in my question that I can run this program without any issues from the terminal.

Comment: And what command do you use to run in the terminal that works?

Comment: `python3 timedttp.py`

Comment: Use full path to the Python script and check permissions on the module directory. Ensure that it's in the system module directory, not a home folder or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named pyvirtualdisplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223333/no-module-named-pyvirtualdisplay)

Comment: this `python3` is the same of `/usr/bin/python3`? Try running the same command.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yeah, it runs either way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble executing Python program in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653576/having-trouble-executing-python-program-in-php)